# how do I post a foreign key by some other field rather than primary key in django rest framework

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I am developing a pet management api and this is what I post to the body when assigning a day of the week to a pet :

```
{
   "day": "Sunday",
   "pet_name": 2 <-- how to add pet name (rather than the primary key)(this is a foreign key)
}
```

How do I pass in the pet name which is the foreign key's field rather than the primary key field.

Comment: You'll have to post more code. Primarly the Serializer class you are using, but it wouldn't hurt to add the view as well. This might make it clear what you mean by `pet name` and the primary/foreign key.

Comment: let me edit my. question :)

Comment: Okay cool, I'll write an answer.

Comment: **Moderator Note** - Please do not overwrite a particular question that you have asked with a completely different and unrelated question. [Ask a new question instead.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid confusion I would rename the `pet_name` property of `Day` to just `pet` as it is referencing the `Pet` model.

```
class Day(models.Model):
    pet = models.ForeignKey(Pet, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

In your `DaySerializer` you can then just use [SlugRelatedField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#slugrelatedfield) to be able to use the pet's `name` to reference the pet.

```
class DaySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    pet_props = PropsSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)
    pet = serializers.SlugRelatedField(slug_field='name')

    class Meta:
        model = models.Day
        fields = ("id", "day", "pet", "pet_props")
```

The representation of this serializer will put the pet's `name` as value for the `pet` field. Also when writing, this allows you to use the pet's `name` to reference the `pet` instance which solves the actual issue in your question.

(You can technically also do `pet_name = serializers.SlugRelatedField(slug_field='name')`, but I would not do that to avoid confusion.)

I would recommend putting a unique constraint on your pet's `name` property though.

Comment: one more question, how do I only allow the user's own pets to. be selected?

Comment: meaning the authenticated user

Comment: only let him get the pet which he has. under his authenticated account

Comment: There's multiple ways of doing that, you could for instance pass your user into the serializer's context and then put in a `validate` method on the serializer (where you then take the user out of the context and verify the fetched `Pet` object). Look into drf serializer validation and if you can't figure it out feel free to ask another question here on Stack Overflow, it would otherwise cloud this question. Could you also put back your serializer and model code back in your original question? That might help people that also stumble upon this question.

Comment: any help? how do I only allow to post pets which a user created ?

Comment: Post a new question and feel free to link it here. Also, why did you unaccept my answer?

Comment: my trackpad was greased up so must've done a double click

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to display some readonly data, you can use [`SerializerMethodField`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield):

```
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist

class DaySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    pet_name = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_pet_name(self, obj):
        try:
            return obj.pet_name.name
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            # the day object doesn't have any
            # pet associated, so return None
            return None
```

---

**Note:** It would be better if you change the `pet_name` foreignkey to `pet` since it's holding a `Pet` instance, and not just its name.

Comment: so instead of assigning a primary key which is a number I will assign an existing pet name right?

Comment: I would not use `SerializerMethodField`, that will only help in the case of fetching the data not when writing the data. My suggestion solution of using `SlugRelatedField` will solve both cases.

Comment: could you provide some code? I am kinda new to this :D

Comment: @GlennDJ Yes, I've mentioned that this solution is for displaying readonly data. It won't be editable.

Comment: thank you so much and one last thing...any course you could recommend for learning rest framework like a pro?

Comment: @RekWolf Consider renaming the `pet_name` field in the `Day` model to `pet`. Then, you can assign the pet using the primary key, and display its name using `pet_name`.

Comment: the pet key has the value of null

Comment: STAY BLESSED! I GOT IT WORKING

Comment: check my question, and please help me with code for what I asked